# Reading AWS Secrets in CloudFormation userdata

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have below CloudFormation Template which Mainly Creates a Secrets and an EC2.
I want to change few config files in EC2 and i need values from Secrets to be put in variables using user data but i am unable to get values from Secrets. Could you please help me with my code

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: builds secretsManager and ec2

Parameters:
  EnvironmentName:
    Type: String
  SharedVpcID:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPC::Id
  SharedPubSubnetID1:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id
  SharedPubSubnetID2:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id
  PrivateSubnetId:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id
  SecretValue: 
    Type: String
    Default: "{{resolve:secretsmanager:${SecretsManager}:SecretString:password}}"
 
Resources:

  SharedVPCDefaultSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
    Properties:
      TemplateURL: https://advanced-artefacts.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/internal/templates/sg/securitygroup.yaml
      Parameters: 
        EnvironmentName: !Ref EnvironmentName
        VPCID: !Ref SharedVpcID 
 
  SecretsManager:
    Type: AWS::SecretsManager::Secret
    Properties:
      Description: 'This is my rds instance secret'
      GenerateSecretString:
        SecretStringTemplate: '{"username": "admin"}'
        GenerateStringKey: 'password'
        PasswordLength: 16
        ExcludeCharacters: '"@/\'

  WebInstance:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
        InstanceType: t2.micro
        ImageId: ami-08b993f76f42xxxxx
        NetworkInterfaces: 
          - AssociatePublicIpAddress: true
            DeviceIndex: "0"
            GroupSet: 
              - !GetAtt SharedVPCDefaultSecurityGroup.Outputs.DefaultSecurityGroup
            SubnetId: !Ref SharedPubSubnetID1
        KeyName: xxx
        UserData:
          Fn::Base64: !Sub |
            #!/bin/bash -xe
              PasswordStr1='{{resolve:secretsmanager:${SecretsManager}:SecretString:password}}'
              export $PasswordStr1
              sudo echo $PasswordStr1
              PasswordStr2={SecretValue}
              export $PasswordStr2
              sudo echo $PasswordStr2
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will sadly not work. Your attempted use secretmanager in userdata is a **security risk** as it would leave your password in plain text in UserData. And also secretmanager dynamic parameters can be used in properties of resources only.

Instead, you should use **AWS CLI** in your user data to obtain the secret from secret manager. This will require [AWS instance role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html) with permissions to access the manager when your UserData executes.